# In which function Prevent Default for jquery.ajaxForm can be done?

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

I am submitting a form by jquery.ajaxForm. But due to double click on mouse the form is submitted twice, I want to Prevent default of clicking the button, but in $.ajaxForm in which event  can i prevent default?

```
$('#counter-entry-form').ajaxForm({

            beforeSubmit: function () {
                $('#counter-entry-form').removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#counter-entry-form'));
                if ($("#counter-entry-form").valid()) {
                    $('#submitting-btn').attr('disabled','disabled');
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.Success) {
                    window.open('@Url.Content("~/Counter/PrintViewForSato?itemId=")' + result.ValueTwo, '_blank');
                    $('#IsFromNameSave').attr('checked', false);
                    $('#IsToNameSave').attr('checked', false);
                    $('#submitting-btn').removeAttr('disabled');
                    if ($('#IsBulkEntry:checked').is(':checked')) {
                        $('#BulkEntryCount').val(result.ReturnId);
                        $('#BulkEntryTotalAmount').val(result.ValueOne);
                        $('#ItemId').val('');
                        $('#ToName').val('');
                        $('#ToDestinationLocal').val('');


                    } else {

                        $('#ItemId').val('');
                        $('#Weight').val(0);
                        $('#FromName').val('');
                        $('#FromDestinationLocal').val('');
                        $('#ToDestinationLocal').val('');
                        $('#ToName').val('');
                        $('#Weight').change();

                    }
                    if ($('#IsReset:checked').is(':checked')) {
                        $('#BulkEntryTotalAmount').val(0);
                        $('#BulkEntryCount').val(0);
                    }
                } else {
                    WorkForce.loader.hide();
                    ShowMessage("error", "error", result.Msg);
                }
            },
            error: function (err) {
                WorkForce.loader.hide();
                if (err.statusText == 'Unauthorized') {
                    ShowMessage('error', 'error', 'Please Login to Continue !!');
                } else {
                    ShowMessage('error', 'error', 'Error !!');
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to disbale submit button on beforeSubmit and and enable it on success or error. Let say your submit button id is 'counter-entry-form-submit-btn'

```
$('#counter-entry-form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function () {
    $('counter-entry-form-submit-btn').attr('disabled','disabled');
    // your code is here
    },
    success: function () {
    $('#counter-entry-form-submit-btn').removeAttr('disabled');
    // your code is here
    },
    error: function () {
    $('#counter-entry-form-submit-btn').removeAttr('disabled');
    // your code is here
    }
});
```

Comment: I have already included same thing in my code which is not working

Comment: ahh, then that button is link or input button tag?